Trouble converting between imperial and metric unit for a volumes of revolution problem
I was trying to calculate the volume of a glass, in U.S. fluid ounces, modelled by the function $$y=x^2$$, where the only other information given is that the radius at the rim of the glass is R=2 inches. I calculated my volume by using $$V=\pi\int_{0}^{R} y \,dy=\left[\frac{\pi}{2}x^4\right]_0^{R}$$ .
As I have always worked with metric units, I thought it would be easier to convert to metric first and then reconvert back to ounces in the end.
I have spent the past 2 hours now, trying to understand why my unit conversions do not work out. 
The answer I got when I converted from inches to meters at the start, and then cubic meters to fluid ounces at the end was approximately 0.35 U.S. fluid ounces, which is incorrect. I did this conversion manually, then using online volume converters to double check.
However, keeping the calculation in inches and then converting cubic inches to fluid ounces at the end did work out to give me the correct 13.93 fluid ounces.
What is the problem here, I can't seem to find out why the answers differ just because one method uses unit conversion?

I don't know what calculations you've made and I don't intend to reverse-engineer them to see which mistake fits the wrong results. One thing that comes to mind is that if $x$ and $y$ in bagoongi are related by $y=x^2$, and $1$ bagoongi is $\alpha$ meters, then $x$ and $y$ in meters (call the quantities $x'$ and $y'$) are related by $\frac1\alpha y'=\left(\frac1\alpha x'\right)^2$, i.e. $y'=\frac1\alpha x'^2$.

$x^4$ is not a 3D volume.
